# iMac Mid 2011 can't boot from recovery USB

Tags: macos, imac, usb, startup, recovery

I am trying to install High Sierra on an old iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011).

First, I tried Internet Recovery, but failed to make any progress and threw a cryptic error. (Something like `-21 06U`, but slightly different each time.)

After that, I figured I could just make a bootable USB stick, but the stick failed to be recognized each time. I tried various versions of OS X and macOS (El Capitan, Yosemite, High Sierra), different methods (first I used TransMac, and then `dd` after converting the DMG to an ISO), and even different USB sticks. Oddly enough, I made a Linux live USB and it booted just fine.

I also checked that the USB was formatted as GPT, not MBR. The iMac hard drive has already been wiped, so currently the Mac does not boot on its own.

Comment: Have you booted with Option pressed so that the iMac sees the USB drive?

Comment: Can you state the model/year and version of macOS (OS X) installed on the other Macs you may have access to?

Comment: @lhf Yes, that's how I was able to boot the Linux drive

Comment: @david-anderson Someone I know has a Macbook from around 2016 running Big Sur

Comment: Have you tried using the instructions posted at the Apple website [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)? You should be able to use a 1016 MacBook to create the bootable USB flash drive installer for High Sierra. BTW, you can use either GPT or MBR.